# Splitting File contents by regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex

As the title stated, I need to split a file by regex in Python.

The lay out of the `.txt` file is as follows

```
[text1]

file contents I need

[some text2]

more file contents I need

[more text 3]

last bit of file contents I need
```

I originally tried splitting the files like so:
`re.split('\[[A-Za-z]+\]\n', data)`

The problem with doing it this way was that it wouldn't capture the blocks that had spaces in between the text within the brackets.

I then tried using a wild card character: `re.split('\[(.*?)\]\n', data)`

The problem I ran into this was that I found it would split the file contents as well. What's the best way to to get the following result: 
`['file contents I need','more file contents I need','last bit of file contents I need']`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps use a capturing group `^\[[^\]\[]*]\r?\n\s*(.*)`  https://regex101.com/r/gcqHXF/1 or if you want to match more lines `^\[[^][]*]\r?\n\s*(.*(?:\r?\n(?!\[[^][]*]).*)*)` https://regex101.com/r/Dor7W5/1

Comment: Or, a bit more capturing, `re.findall(r'(?sm)^\[([^][]*)]\s*(.*?)(?=\n\[[^][]*]|\Z)', text)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/8yAR5m/1)) :)

Comment: Are the text blocks between the `[brace delimiters]` potentially multi line? Does the grouping of those lines between the delimiters have meaning? ie, would you want to identify which block that lines came from?

Comment: @dawg from what I've seen so far, they are not multiline, and I have a strong suspicion they never will be

Comment: The solution I provided below support both multi or single line...

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
txt='''\
[text1]

file contents I need

[some text2]
more file contents I need
multi line at that
[more text 3]

last bit of file contents I need'''
```

(Which could be from a file...)

You can do:

```
>>> [e.strip() for e in re.findall(r'(?<=\])([\s\S]*?)(?=\[|\s*\Z)', txt)]
['file contents I need', 'more file contents I need\nmulti line at that', 'last bit of file contents I need']
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Jg0mD/1)

You can also use `re.finditer` to locate each block of interest:

```
with open(ur_file) as f:
    for i, block in enumerate(re.finditer(r'^\s*\[[^]]*\]([\s\S]*?)(?=^\s*\[[^]]*\]|\Z)', f.read(), flags=re.M)):
        print(i, block.group(1))
```

The individual blocks leading and trailing whitespace can be dealt with as desired...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using re.split, you could use a capturing group with [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) which will return the group 1 values.

In the group, match all the lines that do not start with the `[.....]` pattern

```
^\[[^][]*]\r?\n\s*(.*(?:\r?\n(?!\[[^][]*]).*)*)
```

In parts

- `^` Start of line
- `\[[^][]*]`
- `\r?\n\s*` Match an newline and optional whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `.*` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\r?\n(?!\[[^][]*]).*` Match the line if it does not start with with the `[...]` pattern using a negative lookahead `(?!`
  - `)*`  Close group and repeat 0+ times to get all the lines
- `)` Close group

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dor7W5/1/) or a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/4ZbXOD)

*Example code*

```
import re

regex = r"^\[[^][]*]\r?\n\s*(.*(?:\r?\n(?!\[[^][]*]).*)*)"
data = ("[text1]\n\n"
            "file contents I need\n\n"
            "[some text2]\n\n"
            "more file contents I need\n\n"
            "[more text 3]\n\n"
            "last bit of file contents I need\n"
            "last bit of file contents I need")

matches = re.findall(regex, data, re.MULTILINE)

print(matches)
```

*Output*

```
['file contents I need\n', 'more file contents I need\n', 'last bit of file contents I need\nlast bit of file contents I need']
```